# How can I reinstall Mac OS 9 on a G3 PowerBook's original hard drive?

Tags: powerpc, classic-mac-os, powerbook

I have a PowerBook G3 from 2000 or so and would like to put Mac OS 9 on it for nostalgia reasons. There are games that simply don't perform well with [SheepShaver](https://sheepshaver.cebix.net/), plus networking with SheepShaver isn't reliable with Classic multiplayer games.

- The PowerBook doesn't have a CD-ROM, just a plastic spacer.
- Apparently the PowerBook G3 Pismo and Lombard variants cannot boot from a USB stick
- It has Ethernet, and I have a recent MacBook with an Ethernet dongle, but everything I've read about NetBooting and NetInstalling seems difficult and unapproachable. I tried using [BootMania](http://www2.tba.t-com.ne.jp/beanz/) but it won't let me create an image from any of the Mac OS 9 install disk images I have.
- The PowerBook originally had Linux or BSD on it or something, so a full reformat is needed.
- It has a 20 GB 2.5" IDE drive and I have a USB to IDE adapter, so I can connect the drive to the MacBook with Mac OS X.
- SheepShaver cannot use physical media, so I cannot connect the disk to SheepShaver and run the Mac OS 9 installer on it.

I tried creating a new 512 MB disk from SheepShaver and running the [Mac OS 9.2 Universal Installer](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/126-mac-os-9-2-2-universal-2013-edition-) to install OS9 on it. Then I formatted the physical drive with an Apple Partition Map and the partition as HFS Extended Journaled, then I mounted the drive and copied (dragged over) the files and System Folder from the newly-installed disk image. But when I boot the PowerBook with the drive hooked up I just get the blinking folder icon. If I hold Option I get the Reload and Next buttons but no disks are shown.

I also tried `dd`-ing a working SheepShaver boot image to the physical disk, but I guess that doesn't have a partition map on it or something. It didn't work and `diskutil list` showed it as "Unknown."

Do you have any ideas how I can get Mac OS 9 back on my PowerBook?

Comment: Have you tried booting from an external USB CD drive? According to this post https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/13030/How+can+I+Install+OS+9.2.2 it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried `dd`ing the the [Mac OS 9.2 Universal Installer](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/126-mac-os-9-2-2-universal-2013-edition-) to the hard disk, but that didn't work.

**@jaume put me on the right path, so I `dd`-ed the ISO to a USB stick, held down option at boot, and I'm able to install Mac OS 9 to the original hard disk. Success! Thank you!**

The real thing I learned is that Mac OS 9 boot volumes need half a dozen special driver partitions. Older versions of Mac OS X, up to 10.12 or something, let you partition OS 9 drives correctly using the Disk Utility which had an "Install Mac OS 9 Drivers" option. I used `hdiutil info` to check that the ISO had these partitions.